# Longtable with multicolumn and multirow not working

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow, multicolumn

I'm using a table generated from Excel2Latex in my document. Despite using longtable, the table gets truncated at the end of page after overflowing the bottom margin. Min. working example provided below. It includes some minor modifications made by me to use the \sfrac command and adding a spacing of 1em after some rows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{A long table}
    \begin{longtable}{cccccccc}
    \toprule
       Trial   &       & A     & B     & C     & D     & E     & Outcome \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     & 1     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 0.01 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 1     & 1     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 0.01 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.05 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.05 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.05 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.18 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 9     & 0.32 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 9     & 0.32 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 9     & 0.32 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 0.06 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 3}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} & 9     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 1     & 0.69 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 4}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     & 7     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 0.65 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} &  \sfrac{1}{7}  & 1     & 5     & 5     & 5     & 0.20 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.56 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.56 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.56 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 5}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 9     & 1     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 0.69 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.08 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 6}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} & 9     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 1     & 0.69 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 7}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{3}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 0.04 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 3     & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{5}  &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 3     & 0.10 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & 9     & 5     & 1     & 1     & 9     & 0.41 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} & 9     & 5     & 1     & 1     & 9     & 0.41 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{3}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 0.04 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 8}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{3}  & 5     &  \sfrac{1}{7}  & 5     & 0.13 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 3     & 1     & 9     & 1     & 9     & 0.35 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} &  \sfrac{1}{5}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 0.04 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} & 7     & 1     & 9     & 1     & 9     & 0.45 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} &  \sfrac{1}{5}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 0.04 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 9}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     & 1     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 0.01 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 1     & 1     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 0.01 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.56 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.56 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.56 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 10}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     & 1     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 0.03 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 1     & 1     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 0.08 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.30 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.30 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.30 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 11}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{9}  & 0.02 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 9     & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 3     &  \sfrac{1}{3}  & 0.14 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & 9     & 5     & 1     & 7     & 7     & 0.57 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} & 9     &  \sfrac{1}{3}  &  \sfrac{1}{7}  & 1     & 1     & 0.10 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} & 9     & 3     &  \sfrac{1}{7}  & 1     & 1     & 0.17 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 12}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     & 5     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 0.62 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 1     & 5     & 5     & 5     & 0.22 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.56 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.56 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} &  \sfrac{1}{9}  &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.56 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 13}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.11 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 5     & 1     & 5     & 5     & 5     & 0.56 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.11 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.11 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} & 1     &  \sfrac{1}{5}  & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.11 \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{Trial 14}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.20 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.20 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.20 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.20 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0.20 \\[1em]
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Below is the output. Trials after 9 are missing.

[image: output]

Comment: a `table` is a minipage box it can not break over a page, you can not put `longtable` inside it. Just remove that environment `\centering` has no effect on longtable either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @David for the comment. The solution was to remove the `table` environment. So now I just have

```
\begin{longtable}{cccccccc}
... table contents ...
\end {longtable}
```

It works!